# Publication Date/Time for Duplicate Detection Rules in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: duplicates, dynamics-crm-2011

Is it possible to determine when/who last published a duplicate detection rule in Microsoft Dynamics Crm 2011?

Comment: Could you please explain a little more. The question is unclear please add some more details

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate detection entity has fields for modified by and modified on, if the rule is currently published it cannot be changed. So those fields will show who last published the rule and when.

The fields can be seen on the duplicate detection form.